# How to make a python script execute another command if one does not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, command

Example: suppose I make a code like this: (just an example)

#Start

```
url = 'www.example.com'
response = request.urlopen(url)
result = request.read().decode('utf-8')
print(result) #End
```

But, let's say that I want to implement something that makes the script perform a modification in the code, ex: `utf-8` cannot be decoded, if it happens the code will change or execute some other code that would send it without.`decode(utf-8)`

then it would be:

```
response = request.urlopen(url)
result = response.read().decode('utf-8')
print(result)
```

it is not possible to decode with `utf-8`
then the code changes... or some `command` executes a code below it, and then the code re-executes with:

```
result = response.read()
print (result) **#END**
```

Comment: google exception handling / Try statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example implementation where 1 of 2 commands don't work.

```
def iDontWork():
    # This is a random example, where division by zero will not work.
    return 1/0

def iDoWork():
    # This is a random working method.
    return 1/1

try:
    iDontWork()
except Exception:
    iDoWork()
    print("First function (iDontWork) didn't work, so function the second function (iDoWork) started working.")
```